# To claim a glance from somebody

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

In a text published in 1825 there is the following line:
"There are 18 churches and two convents in this town, which, as well as the popular school and the tribunals, only claim a glance from the traveller."

What is 'to claim a glance from somebody'?
My guesses is
1) to claim gems (money) from somebody... something like that
2) to want/ask somebody to pay attention/to look at.
But I think these are both wrong.
I'm stuck in this. Help!

Comment: It is a figurative usage of claim.

Comment: Well, thanks! But I don't get it anyway. They only claim. That's the meaning?

Comment: They only deserve a glance from tourists, not a visit, probably.

Comment: That's good one! I think I'ma stick to it. Thanks!

Comment: They rarely get a second look.

Comment: @Edwin: Good paraphrasing that neutrally asserts *what actually happens*, avoiding any explicit reference to the possibility that these places might actually be *trying* to attract visitors (or not, as the case may be). Of course, there's also the possibility of alluding to the *traveller's* attitude, in that he might have been somewhere once and decided not to bother going again: *They rarely **merit** a second look.*

Comment: It's not that they (only claim) a glance; it's that they claim (only a glance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two probable meanings come to mind regarding the following portion of the sentence: "only claim a glance from the traveller." Both are dependent on where the emphasis is placed. If the emphasis were placed on *glance*, then the sentence may imply (as user3850720 has stated) that the buildings under consideration do not warrant any further exploration than a cursory glance. If, however, the emphasis were placed on *traveller*, then perhaps the sentence is suggesting that these buildings do not garner the attention they actually deserve from tourists. And since the school is described as "popular" I think that this latter implication is more likely; that although these buildings are appreciated by locals, they do not function as the tourist attractions that they might were they better known.

Essentially, these buildings are overlooked and underappreciated. They can only **claim** a glance, regardless if that is less than they deserve.

Comment: Now, thanks to you and  user3850720, I understand the point of that phrase.

Answer (score 1):

**claim something for someone or something**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/claim) idiom

> to declare rights to or control of something for someone

In this case the meaning:

> "There are 18 churches and two convents in this town, which, as well
>   as the popular school and the tribunals, *were barely noticed* by the
>   traveler."